# OrderBy items inside GroupJoin queryable by string list

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```cs
results = await query
    .GroupJoin(_invitations.GetAll().AsNoTracking()
        .Where(i => i.GroupId == groupId),
        user => user.Id,
        invitation => invitation.UserId,
        (a, s) => new { User = a, Invitation = s})
    .SelectMany(
        ai => ai.Invitation.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (a, s) => new { Users = a.User, Invitations = s }
        )
    .Select(i => i.Users)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Howdy. I have quite simple group join but I can't figure out how to sort invitations inside this group join. Problem is, I don't want to make simple orderBy(i => i.creationDate) but I want to do something like (but on queryable):

```cs
var list = new List<string> {"Fall","Mid","Spring"};
return _db.MiaLog1A.Where(m => m.Campus == selectedCampus)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(m => m.StudentName)
    .ThenBy(m=> list.IndexOf(m.Term));
```

I need to order them by specific strings. Because I have a scenario where newest invitation isn't what I need. I want accepted invitation status first. Is there a way to do this?
I've tried things like that:
.OrderBy(i => sortOrderList.IndexOf(i.InvitationsStatus) in many places but it just throws.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just throws what? "Query could not be translated" ? It might be easier for us to write a query if we have a good idea of what your inputs are, and what you expect your output to be. Without it we might be limited to trying to fix a broken attempt, which could be suboptimal

Comment: It throws Query could not be translated. 
So I need to fetch list of users. And that is query. But additionally I need invitation status for them. Unfortunately some of them have more than one invitation. And I need to get "Approved" as first one in group join. Ordering by date won't work in this case because "Pending" status might be added after approved was already in place. So output from group join should be ordered by strings like "Approved", "Pending", "Not invited" etc.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern of

```
.OrderBy(m => m.StudentName)
.ThenBy(m => m.X == "y" ? 0 : (m.X == "x" ? 1:2))
```

Should translate if you want to sort by "y","x","z"

But I note that both examples you given; (fall, mid, spring) and (approved vs pending / not invited) are sorted in that order anyway.. you don't need to sort by the list index of these, you can just sort the strings ascending